# Map-reduce with escape clause for handling nils

Tags: ruby, mapreduce, inject

So I'm writing some code that computes the cost of various public transport ticket options over a multi-segment journey.  This boils down to computing the cost of each segment (map) and summing them together (reduce aka inject), which is simple enough:

```
total = journey.map {|segment| compute segment}.reduce(:+)
```

Problem is, sometimes `compute` returns `nil` because the segment is not possible for a given ticket, and then the sum operation blows up.  In this case I want to return that `nil` instead, because a single bad segment means the whole journey is invalid.  Currently I'm doing this:

```
fares = journey.map {|segment| compute segment}
total = if fares.include? nil
  nil
else
  fares.reduce(:+)
end
```

Which I can also write as the terse but (IMHO) less readable:

```
fares = journey.map {|segment| compute segment}
total = fares.reduce{|sum, n| (sum.nil? or n.nil?) ? nil : sum + n}
```

But there has to be a nicer way, right...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first "nicer" thing I can think of is:

```
journey.map { |s| compute(s) }.reduce(0) do |sum, fee| 
  break nil unless fee
  sum + fee
end
```

**Update**: This returns `nil` as soon as `compute` returns `nil`:

```
journey.reduce(0) do |sum, segment|
  fee = compute(segment)
  break nil unless fee
  sum + fee
end
```

Comment: OP's problem is, he/she don't want to compute further, if any intermediate `nil` value found.

Comment: +1 for breaking instead of carrying the nil around in the reduce, but Arup is right, it would be even nicer to break in the map phase.  The compute is not hugely expensive though, I'll accept a pretty solution even if it's not super-efficient.

Comment: Updated version works: clean, easy to read and fast!  The checkmark is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below :

```
result = []
journey.take_while { |segment| !(result << compute(segment)).include?(nil) }
total = (result.size == journey.size)  ? result.inject(:+) : nil
```

You may use [`Array#take_while`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-take_while) method :

> Passes elements to the block until the block returns nil or false, then stops iterating and returns an array of all prior elements.

Comment: That's the same as my first solution, only with the if-else replaced by a ternary.

Comment: @jpatokal Did you get this answer ? Else let me know.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Pay attention to `compute segment`, without parentheses it's a syntax error.